# Execute command with pipe from python

Tags: python, bash, popen

I need to pipe a variable text into a bash script using another python script. It does not produce an error but will not trigger the bash script at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi;
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()
import subprocess
import os
import sys

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
lang = ''

# Get data from fields
lang = form.getvalue('lang')
sText = form.getvalue('text')

def sendBashCommand(bCommand):
  p = subprocess.Popen(bCommand.split())
  p.communicate()  # wait until command is done

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
if lang != 'DE' and lang != 'EN':
    lang = 'DE'

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print ""
print "<html><body>"
print "<center><font size=-2>"
print "Spoken text: #" + sText + "# Language: " + lang
print "<br><br>\r\n"

sys.stdout.flush()
sendStr = ''

if sText != '' and lang == 'DE':
  sendStr = "echo " + sText + " |speakpi.DE"
  sendBashCommand(sendStr)
  print sendStr + "<br><br>"
elif sprechText != '' and lang == 'EN':
  sendStr = "echo " + sText + " |speakpi"
  sendBashCommand(sendStr)
  print sendStr + "<br><br>"
else:
  sendStr = ''
  print "Parameter missing<br><br>"

print "done!"
print "</font><br>"
print "</center>"
print "</body></html>"
```

I trigger the cgi with

```
http://myIP/cgi-bin/speak.cgi?text=hello&lang=DE
```

the browser output is as expected.

```
Spoken text: #hello# Language: DE

hello | /usr/local/sbin/speakpi.DE echo hello | /usr/local/sbin/speakpi.DE

done!
```

My guess would be that I messed up the popen part - but I'm lost if it comes to correcting it.
Suggestions?

Comment: (What happens if you query `speak.cgi?text=;+cat+/etc/passwd+#`?)

Comment: You need to use `shell=True` if the command contains shell operators like pipes.

Comment: @David - I know - output is just for debugging and the site is also not available outside LAN but still some risk remains.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks - now the line reads "p = subprocess.Popen(bCommand.split(), shell=True)" but still won't run

Comment: Don't use `split()`.